# Intersection and complement of $\{3^k \mid k \in \Bbb N\}$ and $\{l^3 \mid l \in \Bbb N\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let A = $\{3^k \mid k \in \Bbb N\},\ C = \{l^3 \mid l \in \Bbb N\}$.
>
> a) Determine $A − C$.
>
> b) Determine $A \cap C$.

Approach: if $l=3^k$ then $l^3=3^{3k}$ but we know that $2k \in N$, so $3^{3k}$ is in $A$ and $C$

a) $A-\{3^{3k} \mid k \in \Bbb N\}$
b) $\{3^{3k} \mid k \in \Bbb N\}$

---

> Determine $6\Bbb Z \cap 10 \Bbb Z$.

I got $30 \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, your approach is correct. But, you need to say $l^3\in A$ implies $l^3=3^m$ for some $m$ implies $l=3^k$ for some $k$. For the second question, your answer is again correct. To see this, any integer that is divisible by $300$ is divisible by both $6$ and $10$. On the other hand, if an integer is divisible by $6$ and $10$, it needs to be divisible by their $lcm$, and $lcm(2\cdot3,2\cdot5)=2\cdot3\cdot5=30$